# How to perform ps on several machines to supervise their performance

Tags: linux, performance, bash, shell, unix

I want to supervise the performance of the specified process on several machines. I want to perform

```
ps -eo pcpu,pmem,resident,cutime,cstime,utime,cmd | grep -v grep | grep processToBeSupervised
```

on several machines every 10 second since the supervise job to be launched for 100 seconds and return the standard output of these machine to one of the machine. So the script should be like this:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do 
    ps -eo pcpu,pmem,resident,cutime,cstime,utime,cmd | grep -v grep | grep processToBeSupervised
    echo "--"    
    sleep 10
done
```

For example there are 5 machines, A, B, C, D, and E. A launches the supervise job and after 100 second the report of A, B, C, D, and E should be returned and be stored on A's specified folder.

How should I write this. I just don't know how to give commands from one machine to others.

Comment: I just know how to launch ps command on A from A. Have no idea how to control others from A.

Comment: make bash script to `telnet` OR `ssh` for machine which you want to monitor and run script from machine A.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ssh` with public/private keys set up.

Answer (score 0):

Make a bash script in linux such as "script.sh"

```
execute ps command on machine A
ssh to machine B and collect output of machine B
ssh root@machineB your ps command
ssh to machine C and collect output of machine C
ssh root@machineC your ps command
ssh to machine D and collect output of machine D
ssh root@machineD your ps command
ssh to machine E and collect output of machine E
ssh root@machineE your ps command
```

execute it from terminal

```
./script.sh | tee A's specified folder
```

put this `script.sh | tee A's specified folder` to crontab to execute supervise job automatically after specified time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have the machines exec the `ps` command and show it on a secure web page, and have machine A wget from these machines.